# setup Mac Book Wifi interface as Wifi hotspot using specific DHCP option

Tags: networking, mac, dns, dhcp, dhcp-server

I want to using my Mac Book as an access point.
Besides that I also need to configure its DHCP server to not provide DNS info.
For example, Mac Books AP's ssid is "MacBookHotspot".
While my iPhone connected to "MacBookHotspot", I want the Wifi info displayed my iPhone would be looked like:

```
IP ADDRESS
DHCP(tab)
IP Address    192.168.0.1
Subnet Mask   255.255.255.0
Router        192.168.0.254
DNS           
Search Domains
Client ID
```

(key point: DNS filed is blank)
Does anyone have any good suggestion?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We can separate this into 2 major steps.
1st, to setup your Mac as a Wifi router.
2nd, to configure the router's DHCP options.
1st step is easier, please try to follow the instruction of [How to share Internet connection on a mac](http://www.mactip.net/share-internet-connection-mac/)
Note: There are two parts of this link, please check `Sharing Wired Ethernet connection wirelessly (making a hotspot)` part.

After 1st step, we can see the Wifi icon of the Mac is changed to a wifi sharing icon.
At the mean time, the system will auto generate a `/etc/bootpd.plist` file.
Now click the Mac's wifi sharing icon, and close it.
Open the file with your favorite editor, and you can see it includes the DNS settings like

```
                <key>dhcp_domain_name_server</key>
                <array>
                        <string>192.168.2.1</string>
                </array>
```

Now, please delete these lines, and save the file.
Click the Mac's wifi sharing icon, and open it now.
Done! You can use your iPhone to connect the Mac's SSID, and you will see your DNS is left blank now.

p.s. If you want to configure more DHCP options, maybe you can refer to [Running DHCP on Mountain Lion Server](http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/running-dhcp-on-mountain-lion-server/)

Answer (score 0):

I will admit its been a while since I've done this however just tested again and it still works as I remember.

So using Eethernet to the Mac Book for the internet access then you can share this internally as below:

System Preferences – and clicked “Sharing”. on “Computers using option” – chose Airport.

In AIRPORT OPTIONS, chose a name for the connection and entered security options.

You however cannot change the DHCP options (actually this is not strictly DHCP but more IP passthrough). When I connect my phone to the shared connection it points DNS to my Mac and passes through the Ethernet for the outside world.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By the way I've found a solution for this. If you are still interesting in it, you can try my answer.